# Prove that any group $G$ of order $8$ with $g^2=e$ for all $g \in G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $8$. Prove that if $g^2=e$ for all $g \in G$ then $G$ is abelian.

Not sure how to attack this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: The fact that $|G| = 8$ is completely irrelevant to the problem. Try thinking of two different ways to write the quantity $(ab)^2$, using the fact that $(ab)^2 = e = a^2 b^2$.

Comment: I don't understand why $(ab)^2 = ab$

Comment: @NadiaC It was a typo. It was meant to be $e$.

Comment: Ok. $(ab)^2 = e = a^2b^2 = b^2a^2 = (ba)^2$

Comment: @NadiaC Try writing $a^2 b^2 = e = (ab)^2 = (ab)(ab)$ instead.

Comment: I don't see where are you going with that.

Comment: @NadiaC Simplify $a^2 b^2 = ab ab$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to show?

Comment: @NadiaC If you can show $ab = ba$, that's the definition of abelian.

Comment: Yes I know that. I just cannot get why you started with $(ab)^2$ and not (ab)

Comment: @NadiaC Because thinking about $(ab)^2$ gives me $abab = e$, and thinking about $a^2 b^2$ gives me $aabb = e$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.